# Is there a way to install docker on freeBSD?

Tags: docker, bsd

Is there any way to install docker on FreeBSD? I tried following the official freeBSD handbook but from what i have found the version of docker on FreeBSD is broken (i read that on docker page). i wonder if there is way to install it using older version or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker can be installed on FreeBSD as it is in the repos. As far as whether or not it works is concerned, the last report of it not working and being recommended not to use it was in FreeBSD 10 as it wasn't functional but is reported to work with FreeBSD 11.1 or newer. Podman is also available in the FreeBSD repos as of FreeBSD 13 and functions in the same way. Many find Podman to be a better option than Docker but it's to you to try them out and see what works best for you.